# In Ruby, group_by where I know there's only 1 element per group

Tags: ruby

I have a CSV file where one column is a primary key.  When I do this:

```
CSV.read(ARGV[0], headers: true).group_by {|r| r['myKey']}
```

I get a hash table from key to a list of rows, where the list is always length 1.

Is there a version of `group_by` which asserts that there's only a single value per key, and creates a hash from key to that single value?

Failing that, is there something like `.first` which asserts that there's exactly one element in the array/enumerable?  I like my scripts to fail when my assumptions are wrong, rather than silently return the wrong thing.

Comment: Show some example input and expected output.. :) It helped to answer quickly..

Answer (score 6):

If you use Rails you can use `index_by` method.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the values `r['myKey']` are unique, there's no point in using `group_by`. As I understand the question, you could do this:

```
rows = CSV.read(ARGV[0], headers: true)
Hash[rows.map { |r| r['myKey'] }.zip(rows)]
```

In Ruby 2.0+ the second row could be written:

```
rows.map { |r| r['myKey'] }.zip(rows).to_h
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about Hash[].  Unfortunately, if you do have multiple values, it silently takes the last one, rather than raising an error.  But it's simpler than the 3 line solution, so maybe I'll go with it.

Answer (score 2):

No. I don't believe there is. But you can solve your problem with `each_with_object` like so:

```
CSV.
read(ARGV[0], headers: true).
each_with_object({}) do |r, hash|
  key = r['myKey']
  value = r

  hash[key] = value
end
```

Comment: This is a good answer, though I'd add that you could fulfill the rest of the request by asserting `!hash.key?(key)` before assignment.

Comment: Vote it up. :) And thanks for the correction in the edit. But about the key-existence-check, I'm not sure if that is necessary. According to the OP, `the list is always length 1`

Comment: The list is always supposed to be length 1.  It's always good for code to check assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame Ruby doesn't have this.  Here's what I decided to go on, based on Humza's answer:

```
module Enumerable
  def group_by_uniq
    each_with_object({}) do |value, hash|
      key = yield value
      raise "Multiple values for key \"{key}\"!" unless ! hash.key?(key)
      hash[key] = value
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use your code in you first example you can run this code to check that all hashes are of length 1:

```
raise 'multiple entries per key!' unless my_hash.values.any?{|val| val.size!=1}
```

IF you can get the keys into an array you can check that they do not iclude duplicates by:

```
raise 'multiple entries per key!' unless my_keys.uniq.size == my_keys.size
```

Comment: Hello, hirolau. You've been [AWOL](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=AWOL).